# Is solo mining solve block as same as pool mining?

Tags: proof-of-work, solo-mining

Guys i want to ask tht if solo mining has the same strategy as same as pool mining

I mean the way they guess the block hash

is it the same or not?

Answer (score 2):

A solo pool does not perform shared accounting like a normal pool.

Solo pools also remove the hassle and overhead of running a bitcoin core node for solo miners. Most solo pools provide added features to the stratum v1 mining protocol such as quicker block propagation or job declaration improvements.

A solo pool miner gets the full block minus a (usually) small fee to the solo pool operator.

Comment: Can you explain what a "solo pool" **is**? I have never heard about the concept, and this answer only explains what it achieves, but not how.

Comment: A pool that does not perform shared accounting.

Comment: Huh didn't know that existed either or people wanted it. It is kinda like Blockstream's Greenlight service for Lightning but for mining.

Comment: Solo pools are primarily used by home miners trying to hit a bitcoin block. A lottery of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

The block produced by a mining pool has to satisfy all the same rules that have to be satisfied by a block produced by a solo miner.

The fundamental approach is unchanged - varying contents until the overall hash is not greater than a target.

The details differ because work has to be divided between pool members but this doesn't affect the overall high-level method and goals.

The Bitcoin network protocols do not have specific provison for pools.

Mining pools have their own network protocols for coordinating the pool members but these do not replace any Bitcoin network protocols.

I guess what discourages solo mining is the effect of the granularity of mining rewards combined with the huge disparity between affordable equipment and total network hashpower.

Comment: so thats mean i can still mine on solo pool as usual like pool mining? right?

Comment: I've no idea what a solo pool might mean.